# Import SQL File into existing DB-Table (phpmyadmin)

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have an SQL-File defining a table with 2 columns - product-id and product-reference. I need to import that file into an existing table that has the same structure (plus some extra columns), where product-id corresponds to the product-id from the backup file. Is there a simple way to do that via phpmyadmin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to use `load data infile` (see [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html)) with the `set` option to assign column values.  Columns that are not being set will be given their default values, which is typically `NULL`.

Personally, I would load the data into a staging table with two columns and then `insert` the data from the staging table into the final table.  This makes it easier to validate the data before putting it into the "real" table.

Comment: I went with the latter option, after doing a test locally. Worked like a charm, thanks!